# Pass by reference to a function

Tags: c++

I have following structure of data;

```
typedef struct
{
    char   ElementSectionName[33];  
        ElementType_t    type;                  
    int    nbndry;              
    int    start;               
    int    end;         
    ...
        ...
    int    *Elements;       
        int    *Neighbors;  
} ElementConnectivity;

typedef struct
{
    char   zonename[33];        
        ZoneType_t    Zonetype;     
    int    *Size;           
        ElementConnectivity *ElementCon;
        ...
        ...
    ...
        ZoneGeometry *ZGeom;  
} Zone;

typedef struct
{
    char   basename[33];        
        int    Cell_Dimension;  
        ...
        ...
        ... 
    Zone   *CgnsZone;   
} Base;
typedef struct
{
    float  version;         /* [C] CGNS MLL Version */
    int    Number_of_bases;     /* [C] Number of 'Base' nodes under 'Root' Node 
    Base   *CgnsBase;       /* [C] 'Base' Nodes under the 'Root' Node */
} Root;
```

I have declared two functions as follows;

```
int global(Base *CgnsBase){
  int i,j,node,k;
  FILE *map;FILE *conn;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  cellmapping(CgnsBase->CgnsZone->ElementCon->Elements)
}
```

And the definition of cell mapping is as follows;

```
int cellmapping(int *parEle)
{
 printf("cellmapping.cpp\n");
 printf("Check_point_1\n");
 ...
 ...
 printf(*(parEle+i));
}
```

In main function I have done the following;

```
int main()
 global(CgnsRoot.CgnsBase);
}
```

I was expecting to get the first element of the Elements array because I have some elements in that array and I have passed as a pointer but I am getting junk value. Why is it so? Where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Impossible to debug with so few information. For example in `printf(*(parEle+i));`, what is `i`? What is `parEle` and are you sure it points to an array with more than 1 element? Adding something to a pointer might go out of bounds and cause UB.

Answer (score 0):

Where CgnsRoot?
I assume Root..
try to change typedef to simple stuct tag

```
struct ElementConnectivity
{
    char   ElementSectionName[33];  
        ElementType_t    type;                  
    int    nbndry;              
    int    start;               
    int    end;         
    ...
        ...
    int    *Elements;       
        int    *Neighbors;  
};

struct Zone
{
    char   zonename[33];        
        ZoneType_t    Zonetype;     
    int    *Size;           
        ElementConnectivity *ElementCon;
        ...
        ...
    ...
        ZoneGeometry *ZGeom;  
};

struct Base
{
    char   basename[33];        
        int    Cell_Dimension;  
        ...
        ...
        ... 
    Zone   *CgnsZone;   
}e;
struct Root
{
    float  version;         /* [C] CGNS MLL Version */
    int    Number_of_bases;     /* [C] Number of 'Base' nodes under 'Root' Node 
    Base   *CgnsBase;       /* [C] 'Base' Nodes under the 'Root' Node */
};

int global(Base *CgnsBase){
  int i,j,node,k;
  FILE *map;FILE *conn;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  cellmapping(CgnsBase->CgnsZone->ElementCon->Elements)
}

int main()
 global(CgnsRoot.CgnsBase);
}
```

I've to leave... to be continued